# Why remove class in js doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing one of the FrontEndMentor challenges and I wanted to make an accordion thingy by Bootstrap and  I think I've messed up a bit. Could you help me a bit? I'm running out of ideas...

What I wanted to do is, once I click on the card's header it supposed to show us a paragraph's content and make h2 bolded (class `active` sets font-weight to 700). When I clicked on the other card's header it closes the first one and does the same as with the previous one and it works. But when I click twice on the same card's header then paragraph disappears as it supposed to but the header is still bolded and class `active` remains active.

I wrote the function that looping over all headers on click and removes `active` class before adding a class to the new element.
**HTML Code:**

```js
const allHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".cardHeader");
/* looping over h2 and removing class active */
function removeClass() {
    for (let cardHeader of allHeaders) {
        const h2Header = cardHeader.firstElementChild;
        h2Header.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

for (let cardHeader of allHeaders) {
    cardHeader.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const h2Header = cardHeader.firstElementChild;
        removeClass();
        h2Header.classList.toggle("active");
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="cardItem">
        <div class="cardHeader" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <h2>How many team members can I invite?</h2>
        </div>
        <p id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Lorem ipsum
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
            team members for the Premium plan.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cardItem">
        <div class="cardHeader" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <h2>What is the maximum file upload size?</h2>
        </div>
        <p id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">No more than 2GB. All files in your
            account
            must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I described the sequence of actions with comments below in the code.

```
const allHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".cardHeader");

for (let cardHeader of allHeaders) {
    cardHeader.addEventListener("click", function () {
        toggleFunction(this);
    });
}

function toggleFunction(x) {
    // Remove all active classes
    for (let cardHeader of allHeaders) {
        var h2Header = cardHeader.firstElementChild;
        h2Header.classList.remove("active");
    }

    // Get paren of clicked element and get element with class ".collapse" in it. 
    // Check if this element have "show" class.
    var y = x.parentElement.querySelector('.collapse').classList.contains('show');

    // Add or Remove "active" class on clicked child "h2" element
    var h2Header = x.firstElementChild;
    if (y) {
        h2Header.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
        h2Header.classList.add("active");
    }
}
```